# Bokeh is not rendering properly multipolygon (islands) from GeoJson

Tags: python, geojson, bokeh

I'm rendering a choropleth map on Bokeh. My geodata is an GeoJSON with Polygons and MultiPolygons.

I have trouble rendering the Multipolygons:

If I extract all geometries of an feature (four islands, for example, in one list) their plot doesn't 'cut' between figures, and they seems all one.
It shows some 'spiderweb' stuff, crossing unorderly all the points.

If I create one list for island (I assume that it is the correct way to work this), Bokeh doesn't plot anything. Not even the grid (only the toolbar)....and doesn't show any error.

Probably it's some issue with the output of the function 'obtCoordMultipoligono'.

I've searched for examples on islands, but nothing coudn't help me.

Thanks in advance.

***Update:***
I add my snippets. They are fragments of original, but functional.
The idea is an output like the 'Texas unemployment' on the BokehGallery, but my country has islands on it.

My GeoJSON in **argentina.json** (extract 1 multipolygon only; i don't have issues with polygons):

```
    {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [

    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                -59.68266601562502,
                -52.231640624999976
              ],
              [
                -59.74658203124997,
                -52.25087890624999
              ],
              [
                -59.76445312499996,
                -52.2421875
              ],
              [
                -59.784863281249955,
                -52.2046875
              ],
              [
                -59.78593749999999,
                -52.156152343749966
              ],
              [
                -59.79331054687498,
                -52.134179687500016
              ],
              [
                -59.75322265624999,
                -52.14140624999998
              ],
              [
                -59.681005859375034,
                -52.18007812499995
              ],
              [
                -59.68266601562502,
                -52.231640624999976
              ]
            ]
          ],
          [
            [
              [
                -58.438818359375006,
                -52.011035156249974
              ],
              [
                -58.432714843750006,
                -52.09902343749996
              ],
              [
                -58.512841796874966,
                -52.071093750000045
              ],
              [
                -58.54140625000002,
                -52.02841796874996
              ],
              [
                -58.49707031249997,
                -51.99941406250001
              ],
              [
                -58.46054687499998,
                -52.0015625
              ],
              [
                -58.438818359375006,
                -52.011035156249974
              ]
            ]
          ],
          [
            [
              [
                -61.01875,
                -51.7857421875
              ],
              [
                -60.94726562499997,
                -51.79951171875005
              ],
              [
                -60.87597656250003,
                -51.79423828125004
              ],
              [
                -60.91616210937494,
                -51.89697265625001
              ],
              [
                -60.94755859374996,
                -51.94628906250002
              ],
              [
                -61.031982421875,
                -51.94248046875004
              ],
              [
                -61.11577148437493,
                -51.87529296875003
              ],
              [
                -61.14501953125003,
                -51.83945312500001
              ],
              [
                -61.05166015625002,
                -51.81396484374997
              ],
              [
                -61.01875,
                -51.7857421875
              ]
            ]
          ],
          [
            [
              [
                -60.11171875000002,
                -51.39589843749998
              ],
              [
                -60.24882812499996,
                -51.39599609375
              ],
              [
                -60.27587890624997,
                -51.36318359374997
              ],
              [
                -60.275341796874955,
                -51.28056640625002
              ],
              [
                -60.17138671875,
                -51.273437499999986
              ],
              [
                -60.06982421875,
                -51.307910156249996
              ],
              [
                -60.07646484374993,
                -51.34257812500004
              ],
              [
                -60.11171875000002,
                -51.39589843749998
              ]
            ]
          ]

        ]
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "perimeter": 0,
        "vista": "mim",
        "provincia": "Islas Malvinas",
        "objectid": 24,
        "prov": 0,
        "bounds": [
          0,
          0
        ],
        "provif3_": 27.0,
        "ogc_fid": 26,
        "provif3_id": 26.0
      }
    }
    ]
    }
```

My data in **PBIArg.csv**:

`24,AR-V,Islas,13245`

My code:

```
<!-- language: lang-py -->

import json,pprint,csv
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file, ColumnDataSource
import pandas as pd
from osgeo import ogr

fname = r'islas.json' # constante hasta conseguir algo mejor
dname = r'PBIArg.csv' # variable estadística a graficar.



paleta = ["#FFF5F0", "#FEE0D2", "#FCBBA1", "#FC9272", "#FB6A4A", "#EF3B2C", "#CB181D", "#99000D"]


def colorante(rate,max_value,min_value,paleta):
    try:
        intensidad = int(float(len(paleta)-1) * float(rate - min_value) / float(max_value - min_value))
        return paleta[intensidad]
    except:
        intensidad = int(float(len(paleta)-1) * float(rate - min_value) / float(max_value - min_value))
        return paleta[intensidad]


def obtCoordMultipoligono(pcia):
    mpoly = ogr.CreateGeometryFromJson(pcia)

    print('pcia-MPOLY tiene esta cantidad de islas: ', mpoly.GetGeometryCount()) 
    coordX,coordY = [],[]

    # idx poly mpoly
    for idx, poly in enumerate(mpoly): #itero mpoly
        print('POLY tiene esta cantidad de islas: ', poly.GetGeometryCount()) 
        innerX,innerY = [],[]
        # ind 
        for ind in range(0, poly.GetGeometryCount()): #itero poly
            innerPoly = poly.GetGeometryRef(ind)
            print('INNERPOLY tiene esta cantidad de PUNTOS: ', innerPoly.GetPointCount()) 
            lastX,lastY = [],[]
            for i in range(0, innerPoly.GetPointCount()): #itero innerpoly
                # GetPoint returns a tuple not a Geometry
                punto = innerPoly.GetPoint(i)
                print('pto obtenido en X',punto[0])
                # Asigno a lista local
                lastX.append(punto[0])
                lastY.append(punto[1])
            print('LastX:')
            pp.pprint(lastX)
            innerX.append(lastX)
            innerY.append(lastY)
        print('InnerX:')
        pp.pprint(innerX)
        coordX.append(innerX)
        coordY.append(innerY)
        print('CoordX:')
        pp.pprint(coordX)
    dictCoord = dict(coordX=coordX,coordY=coordY)
    print('DictCoord:')
    pp.pprint(dictCoord)
    return dictCoord

############  MAIN  ##################
######## Leo csv estadísticas ########

with open(dname, 'r') as f:
    '''Leo el CSV, creo diccio de pciaID: estadísticaPcial.
    Abajo busco la estadísticaPcial max y min para luego calcular los colores'''
    max_value, min_value = 0,0
    datos = {}
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        estadistica = int(row[3])
        datos[row[0]] = estadistica
        if estadistica > max_value:
            max_value = estadistica
        if estadistica < min_value:
            min_value = estadistica

######## Leo geojson ########            
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    geojson = f.read()
    geoDict = json.loads(geojson)

######## Parseo geojson ########

dictArg = {}
for pcia in geoDict['features']:
    pciaID = str(pcia['properties']['objectid'])
    nombrePcia = pcia['properties']['provincia']
    coordX = []
    coordY = []

    if pcia['geometry']['type'] == 'Polygon':
        for punto in pcia['geometry']['coordinates'][0]:
            if len(punto) == 2:
                coordX.append(punto[0])
                coordY.append(punto[1])
    elif pcia['geometry']['type'] == 'MultiPolygon': 
        multiJSON = json.dumps(pcia['geometry'])
        dictCoord = obtCoordMultipoligono(multiJSON)
        # print(dictCoord)
        coordX = dictCoord['coordX']
        coordY = dictCoord['coordY']

    # Handling states without data
    try:
        info=int(datos[pciaID])
    except KeyError:
        info = 0    
    color = colorante(info,max_value,min_value,paleta)
    dictPcia = dict(nombre=nombrePcia,coordX=coordX,coordY=coordY, info=info,color=color)
    dictArg[pciaID] = dictPcia
    print('dict',dictArg['19'])

######## saco coord de las pcias ########
provincias = {
    codPcia: nombrePcia for codPcia, nombrePcia in dictArg.items()
}

# print(provincias)
pcia_xs = [provincia['coordX'] for provincia in provincias.values()]
pcia_ys = [provincia['coordY'] for provincia in provincias.values()]

nombres_provincias = [provincia['nombre'] for provincia in provincias.values()]

######## Saco estadísticas de las pcias ########
provincias_datos = [provincia['info'] for provincia in provincias.values()]

######## Coloreo el mapa a nivel datos ########

provincias_colores = [provincia['color'] for provincia in provincias.values()]

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x=pcia_xs,
    y=pcia_ys,
    color=provincias_colores,
    nombre=nombres_provincias,
    dato=provincias_datos,
))

TOOLS="pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,hover,save"

p = figure(title="PBI de Argentina por provincia", tools=TOOLS)

p.patches('x', 'y', source=source,
          fill_color='color', fill_alpha=0.9,
          line_color='#767676', line_width=1.5)

hover = p.select_one(HoverTool)
hover.point_policy = "follow_mouse"
hover.tooltips = [
    ("State:", "@nombre"),
    ("Nº:", "@dato"),

]

output_file("PBIar.html", title="Testing islands in bokeh")

show(p)
```

Comment: Can you update your post and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that people could try to run?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I cut the code and could post it.

Comment: The idea behind Bokeh's patches is that you need to separate different 'rings' with a 'nan' value. That should avoid having everything connected. But see my answer below for something easier, which avoids all the manual parsing all together.

Comment: Tell me if I understand this well: If a put an Nan point between islands it would work?

Comment: Yes, it then doesn't draw a line between individual rings (islands in this case). But I wouldn't give up on the GeoJSONDataSource just yet. Its so much more convenient, I think your issue has a different origin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of following the original 'Texas example', you can significantly simplify your code if you use Bokeh's `GeoJSONDataSource`.

A trimmed down example using your geojson could look like:

```
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook, output_file
from bokeh.models import (
    GeoJSONDataSource,
    HoverTool,
    LinearColorMapper
)
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis6

with open(r'argentina.geojson', 'r') as f:
    geo_source = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson=f.read())


color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette=Viridis6)

TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,hover,save"

p = figure(title="Argentina", tools=TOOLS, x_axis_location=None, y_axis_location=None, width=500, height=300)
p.grid.grid_line_color = None

p.patches('xs', 'ys', fill_alpha=0.7, fill_color={'field': 'objectid', 'transform': color_mapper}, 
          line_color='white', line_width=0.5, source=geo_source)


hover = p.select_one(HoverTool)
hover.point_policy = "follow_mouse"
hover.tooltips = [("Provincia:", "@provincia")]

output_file("PBIar.html", title="Testing islands in bokeh")

show(p)
```

The output then looks like:
[image]

#### Edit:

This is what the output looks like when using the entire geojson as mentioned in the comments below.

[image]

And zoomed in on the islands in the south:

[image]

#### Update: functionality with variable data

I added this function in order to edit the geoJSON in an interactive way, depending on a JSON data passed.

The geoJSON now has the 'data' property and the state international code (property: 'ISO_3166-2').

The JSON data is like this:

```
{
"AR-A": "7",
"AR-B": "53",
"AR-C": "46"
}
```

The function reads the geoJSON and asign the data:

```
def asignDataToStates(geo,data):
    for pcia in geo['features']:
        codPcia = str(pcia['properties']['ISO_3166-2'])
        
        if codPcia in data.keys():
            if data.values() != 0:
                pcia['properties']['data'] = data[codPcia]
    dataJson = json.dumps(geo,ensure_ascii=True)
    return dataJson
```

Comment: It's very good your solution (actually, it were worked so easy for the polygons part), but it isnt working for multipolygons (or at least I assumed that it is the reason for the error 'column name nonexistent' that gives me when I try with the whole country (one feature with Polys and multipolys).

Comment: I'm gonna see the option that you gived me on the commentary. :)
Thanks a lot for both of them :) :)

Comment: The json you shared, and I used, is a multipolygon. I don't think that's the issue. I've used two attributes from your json for the colormapping and the hover, these are "objectid" and "provincia". Are these still attributes in the data you are trying to use?

Comment: Is the data you are using publically available? It might help clear things up, since I can't replicate the error you experience.

Comment: Here is: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jazzido/Polymaps-Argentina/master/provincias.json

Comment: Thanks, it works fine for me in Bokeh 0.12.3, what version are you using? I see for example "Tierra del Fuego" show up as several, unconnected, polygons. The color_mapper is fairly recent I think, maybe that's causing problems. If you cant upgrade, setting 'fill_color="grey"' might solve it.