# GeoPandas and Bokeh extract xs and ys from data - WorldMap

Tags: python, plot, bokeh, geopandas

I found this post on [Geopandas and bokeh extract xs and ys from data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56029601/geopandas-and-bokeh-extract-xs-and-ys-from-data)

What I need is  basically the same thing but for the map of the whole world (extract XS and ys from GeoPandas and convert into bokeh readable format). I am struggling with the fact the world data has both polygons and multi polygons.

If anyone can help, that would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a GeoJSON. Bokeh provides a `GeoJSONDataSource` wich can handle this. May this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226189/bokeh-is-not-rendering-properly-multipolygon-islands-from-geojson) helps you.

Comment: @mosc9575 yes, I have everything installed. I solved it (will post a solution). Now the only thing I am running into is the runtime error. I found some sort of solution for that (is included in the code). I've seen people also say that one way of solving it is to downgrade bokeh. 
Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can run a `GeoJSON` using pandas `GeoJSONDataSource` like I mentioned in my comment.

```
from bokeh.models import GeoJSONDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
import geopandas as gp

output_notebook()

world = gp.read_file(gp.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
geo_source = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson=world.to_json())

p = figure(title='World', tooltips=[('Country', '@name')],
           x_range=(-180, 180), y_range=(-90, 90), 
           x_axis_location=None, y_axis_location=None,
           plot_width=1000, plot_height=500
          )
p.patches('xs', 'ys', fill_alpha=0.4, fill_color='grey', 
          line_color='black', line_width=0.5, source=geo_source
         )
show(p)
```

**Output**

[image: world]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I solved it but it needs polishing. If you have any ideas how to improve, let me know. I am also running into a runtime error and that is either solved by uncommenting certain parts of code (marked in the code) or by downgrading bokeh. I have not tried downgrading bokeh, I just saw that answer somewhere.

(Also, I have never posted on SO before so I am not really sure how this whole thing works so be gentle).

https://github.com/nikosarcevic/GeoMapping

Comment: Hi Niko. Please check my answer. Hope this works on your machine, too. I think this simplifys your code.

Comment: Hi back, @mosc9575 - I just checked and it works! TYSM!Super grateful!  It definitely looks simpler than my solution.
I cannot comment on json as at times it feels like witchcraft XD

Comment: one more question, @mosc9575 - did you encounter runtime error when re-running the cell?
I get this often so I have to restart the kernel which is super annoying

RuntimeError: Models must be owned by only a single document, Selection(id='1060', ...) is already in a doc

Comment: And no. I did not have any problems with the runtime. Do you have problems with my code?

Comment: no, yours runs smoothly!

I also noticed I am not running into errors with my solution now when I copied all parts of the code into one cell. I was reading the csv (am over plotting some data over the world map) and defining pandas df and source in a separate cell. who knows.
vielen dank!

Comment: Would you consider to mark my answer as acccepted?

Comment: @mosc9575 definitely! I did but I am still fresh here so my answer/rating does not show up (that is what popped up when I rated it).